# NavLink is not rendering the child buttons as per the css styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I have a component called Header which has 2 Navlinks for 2 buttons add and view respectively. The header component is common across the app, which has been incorporated in Approutes.js. For some reason the second button view is not getting rendered as per the css styling.

Approutes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
const Approutes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Approutes;
```

Home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class  Home extends Component {

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="home">
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Header.js:-

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="appTitle">
          <h1>NEW APP</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="navLinks">
          <NavLink
            to="/create"
            className="addBtn"
            activeClassName="activeButton"
          >
            ADD
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/view"
            className="viewBtn"
            activeClassName="activeButton"
          >
            VIEW
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Header;
```

CSS FILE:-

```
.home {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

}
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0vh;
  left: 3vw;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.appTitle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.navLinks {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  width: 95vw;
  border: 2px solid black

}

a:first-child {
  float: left;
}

.addBtn,.viewBtn {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 47.5vw !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: skyblue;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 280ms ease-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activeButton {
    background: lighten(rgba(7, 116, 241, 0.9), 10%);
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    transition: all 280ms ease-in;
    color: white;
    width: 47.5vw !important;

  }
```

View button misalignment:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably problem is here:

```
a:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

Link by default is inline element (`width` is ignored). When you make it floating, it becomes block element (`width` working). But you apply this only to first link. Try to replace this part with:

```
.navLinks a {
  float: left;
}
```

Additionally, links have a lot of [states](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/link-pseudo-classes/). You might need to define styles for each state, i.e. `.viewBtn,.viewBtn:visited,.viewBtn:hover,.addBtnviewBtn:focus,.viewBtn:active,`

Comment: Yeah this one was a tricky one to catch. Thanks a lot. It is working as desired now.